# Cannot find react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get this odd error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/MapMarkerNativeComponent.js 14:48-113                                                                             
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeCommands' in '/home/ubuntu/pdev/me/website/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib'
```

However, I have react-native installed:

```
ubuntu@foo:~/pdev/me/website$ npm list | grep react-native
├── @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.10                           
├── @react-native-picker/picker@2.4.4                                           
├── react-native-elements@3.4.2                                                                                                                                 
├── react-native-expo-viewport-units@0.0.8                                                                                                                      
├── react-native-gesture-handler@2.6.0                                                                                                                          
├── react-native-maps@1.3.1                                                                                                                                     
├── react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.3                                                                                                                        
├── react-native-text-size@4.0.0-rc.1                                                                                                                           
├── react-native-vector-icons@9.2.0                                                                                                                             
├── react-native-web@0.18.9                                                                                                                                     
├── react-native@0.70.0
```